# Python equivalent to C++ adjacency list

Tags: python, c++, matrix

I have decided to learn Python. I have a background in c++ so there are some challenges I have wrapping my brain around Python. My question is:

I have the following syntax in C++ and I am looking for an equivalent in Python. This is just a snippet of code. I'm not sure if I should use lists or Dicts.

```
int main()
{
    ...some code...

    int** matrix = 0;
    buildmatrix(vertices,matrix);

    ...some more code...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void buildmatrix(int& vertices,int** &matrix)
{
    cout <<"Enter # of vertices -> ";
    cin >>vertices;

    matrix = new int* [vertices];       
    for(int i=0; i<vertices; i++)       
     {
      matrix[i] = new int[vertices];    
     }
     ...some more code...
}
```

In short this builds a pointer array of arrays. Making it look like a matrix. What is the best data structures and or methods to use in converting this code to Python?

Comment: So lists in python can do pointer to pointer arrays (ie. dynamic two-dimensional arrays)?

Comment: Yes, you can easily have a list of lists, which is the closest analogy to your C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python translation of your code would be:

```
def buildmatrix():
    vertices = int(raw_input("Enter # of vertices -> ")

    matrix = []      
    for i in range(vertices):
        matrix.append([])
    # alternatively, matrix = [[] for _ in range(vertices)]

    return vertices, matrix

def add_edge(matrix, vertex1, vertex2):
     matrix[vertex1].append(vertex2)
     matrix[vertex2].append(vertex1)
```

This works because there's no restriction on what the elements of a list can be. Here, each element is another list, which can have any length. You can change the length of a list whenever you like, which we do here with .append(), so you don't need to preallocate space in the adjacency lists.

Comment: So to display the matrix after edges have been inserted. I can reference the matrix by: print matrix[i][j]?

Comment: Why not just try it, Scott?

Answer (score 0):

Dicts are what other languages might call associated arrays or hashmaps. Lists are containers of arbitrary length. If you need an equivalent to an array, use a list.

You should do an introductory Python tutorial; the difference between lists and arrays is pretty fundamental and would be explained there.

Comment: So lists in python can do pointer to pointer arrays (ie. dynamic two-dimensional arrays)?

Comment: It's probably a mistake to think in terms of pointers in Python; we have references instead. But yes, a list can contain any kind of object, including another list.

Comment: So a list of lists sounds like an approach to take to the problem but not necessarily the only one.

Answer (score 0):

A container in C++ is restricted to one type of object. A `std::vector<SomeType>` can only contain elements of type `SomeType`. A `std::list<SomeOtherType>` can only contain elements of type `SomeOtherType`. A `std::map<KeyType,ValueType>` can only map keys of type `KeyType` to values of type `ValueType`. And so on.

That isn't true in python. There's nothing wrong with `mixed_up_list = ["a", 1, [2, 3, 4]]`. Lists in python can contain numbers, strings, tuples, lists, dicts, objects, in short, anything. How you use lists in python is up to you. Note the last element in my `mixed_up_list`. It's a python list.  Your adjacency list can easily be represented in a python list, and without all the allocation / deallocation you have to worry about with C++.